# 20.04 switching gnome to horizontal workspaces and now back to vertical has broken window titlebar menus

Tags: 20.04, gnome, workspaces

I have recently upgraded 2 xubuntu boxes from 16.04 to ubuntu 20.04.  Changing from xfce to gnome inspired me to play with a few settings via gnome-tweaks, gnome-shell-extensions etc.

One of the tweaks offered to switch me to horizontal-workspaces instead of vertical.  I experimented with this on box-1 but then switched back to "standard" ie vertical workspaces.

However ... now on box-1 I have a minor problem. When I right-click on a window titlebar I see 4 menu options to "Move to workspace Left/Right/Up/Down".  I have tried to replicate this on box-2 but I only ever see 2 menu options.  Either Up and Down, or Left and Right.  Never all 4.  Presumably I have left behind some orphan settings somewhere, but I can't find anything that looks relevant, and I'm not sure which extension caused the problem.

Any idea how to clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by a set of extensions from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/

If extension "workspace-wrap-around" is turned on then the titlebar menu issue arises.  A shame because the wrap-around is otherwise quite useful.

Comment: Did you try to build the Just Perfection extension manually? (restart GNOME Shell after that).